# 4th root question/guidance

Tags: polar-coordinates

Find all 4th roots of $-8 + 8i\sqrt 3$

$a=-8$

$b=8\sqrt 3$

$r= \sqrt{a^2+b^2}= \sqrt {(-8^2)+(8\sqrt{3})^2)}=\sqrt{64+192}=\sqrt {256} =16$

$\frac ar= cos\theta=\frac{-1}{2}$     $\space     $ $\frac br= sin\theta$=$\frac {\sqrt3}{2}$

This gives me a different $\theta$ one being 120 degrees and the other 60 degrees

I can get the roots I just don't see were I am making the mistake with $\theta$, after that point I can finish it off myself.

Comment: Upvotes, but no hints? Ok, The given complex number is in the second quadrant (Make a sketch!). Therefore the angle is between 90 and 180 degrees. In this case, 120 (Use arctan) degrees. So this is the angle you need to divide by 4, which is 30 degrees, and then add multiples of 90 degrees to obtain all the angles needed to go for RCIS

Comment: @imranfat mind double checking if I set up r's correctly for him. Also then z1 in rectangular is $\sqrt(3) + i$

Comment: Both $60$ and $120$ degrees have sine equal to $\sqrt{3}/2$, but only $120$ degrees has cosine equal to $-1/2$, so you should use that as the argument of $-8+8i\sqrt{3}$.  That is to say, the number is $16 \text{ cis } 120$.

Comment: @BrianTung So all is well with I what Posted below? and is that rectangular correction also their

Comment: @ELO: Looks all right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polar form:

$z_1= 2(\cos 30 + i \sin 30)$

$z_2= 2(\cos 120 + i \sin 120)$

$z_3= 2(\cos 210 + i \sin 210)$

$z_4= 2(\cos 300 + i \sin 300)$

Rectangular Form:

$z_1= 2(\frac {\sqrt{3}}{2} + i \frac 12) = \sqrt {3} + i$

$z_2= 2(-\frac 12 + i\frac {\sqrt{3}}{2} ) =-1 +i \sqrt {3}$

$z_3= 2(-\frac {\sqrt{3}}{2} - i \frac 12)=-\sqrt {3}  -i$

$z_4= 2(\frac 12 - i\frac {\sqrt{3}}{2}) = 1 -i\sqrt {3}$